# autologin not working after upgrade

Tags: auto-login

I installed ubuntu 18.04.1 and autologing in worked great, after running apt-upgrade autologin stops working and I'm confronted with a login screen after boot. How can I get autologin to work again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did get it to work, the documentation needs to be changed as there is no unlock in the corner. What you have to do is choose advanced, then check don't ask password at login.

Answer (score 0):

The following is what is stated in the [Ubuntu Official Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/user-autologin.html.en).

1. Open the Activities overview and start typing Users.
2. Click Users to open the panel.
3. Select the user account that you want to log in to automatically at startup.
4. Press Unlock in the top right corner and type in your password when prompted.
5. Toggle the Automatic Login switch to ON.

Comment: Yes tried this, it still prompts me for a user after boot on upgraded version.